# When I type the following code, the table comes above the question. How can I make it appear below the question?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

```
\begin{question}
Calculate the reverberation time of hall of 1500 \si{m^3} volume
having a seating capacity for 120 persons when \\
(i) when the hall is empty \\ 
(ii) with full capacity audience \\
(iii) audience occupying the cushioned seats with following data:
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c |}
  \hline
  \textbf{Surface} & \textbf{Area (\si{m^2})} & \textbf{Coefficient of
    absorption (O W U)} \\
  \hline
  Plastered walls & 112 & 0.03 \\
  Wooden floor & 130 & 0.06 \\
  Plastered ceiling & 170 & 0.04 \\
  Wooden door & 20 & 0.06 \\
  \hline
  Cushioned chairs (Nos.) & 100 & 1.0 \\
  Audience (Nos.) & 120 & 4.7 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Remove the `\begin{table}` and `\end{table}` lines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `table` environment is for floating tables. If you don't want your tabular material to move, omit it and just use `tabular`.

Comment: If you want some vertical spacing, you can replace the `table` environment with `center`, and if you want a caption, you can use `\captionof{table}{some caption}` (this command is defined in the `caption` and in the `capt-of` packages).

Answer (score 1):

- The `table`-environment is used to get floating tabulars, if you do not want a tabular to float, just do not use it. You can use a simple `center`-environment instead.
- If you want a caption for this tabular, load the `caption`-package and use the `\captionof{table}{Bla Bla}` command. Captions for tables should be above the table.
- Use `siunitx` properly, for a number use `\num{1e3}`, for a number with unit use `\SI{1500}{\cubic\meter}`
- Use the S-column option of siunitx for data colums, it aligns the numbers at their decimal point and allows you to specify the format with the `table-format` option.
- do not use vertical lines in tables. `booktabs` offers special lines with proper spacing. It is highly recommanded to use them (and to read the documentation)
- You should not hard-code enumerations, use the list-environments. If you need to customize the lists, have a look at the `enumitem` package. It offers very high customizability of the latex lists and the possibility to resume an old enumeration.

You should give a compilable example, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{exsheets}   % i assumed you used this package
\usepackage{booktabs}   % for the top/bottom/midrule commands
\usepackage{siunitx}    % use it everwhere you can and all of it's commands
\usepackage{enumitem}   % for custamisation of enumerate and other lists
\usepackage{caption}    % for the \captionof command

\begin{document}

\begin{question}
    Calculate the reverberation time of hall of \SI{1500}{\cubic\metre} volume
    having a seating capacity for 120 persons when
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*), nosep]
        \item when the hall is empty
        \item with full capacity audience
        \item audience occupying the cushioned seats with following data:
    \end{enumerate}
    \begin{center}
        \captionof{table}{Data for the Question}
        \begin{tabular}{l  S[table-format=3.0]  S[table-format=1.2]}
            \toprule
            {Surface} & {Area / \si{m^2}} & {Coefficient of absorption / O W U} \\
            \midrule
            Plastered walls         & 112 & 0.03 \\
            Wooden floor            & 130 & 0.06 \\
            Plastered ceiling       & 170 & 0.04 \\
            Wooden door             & 20  & 0.06 \\
            \midrule
            Cushioned chairs (Nos.) & 100 & 1.0 \\
            Audience (Nos.)         & 120 & 4.7 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Output]